# StateProvider somewhere else than app.js in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url

I'd like to know if I can put a stateprovider somewhere else than my app.js, because it causes me some problems in other pages.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'templates/step_Form/form.html?v=' + new Date().getDay()
    })

    // url will be nested (/form/profile)
    .state('form.upload', {
        url: '/upload',
        templateUrl: 'templates/step_Form/form-upload.html?v=' + new Date().getDay()
    })

        // url will be /form/interests
    .state('form.content', {
        url: '/content',
        templateUrl: 'templates/step_Form/form-content.html?v=' + new Date().getDay()
    })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/upload');
})
```

My controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ImportGeneralCtrl', function ($scope, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

//myfunctions

}
```

I integrated a multi-step form in my HTML, using the state provider. 
How could i get out the state provider from app.js to only apply it on my controller?

Comment: Usually, controllers would go with states or states would map to components that have controllers.  IIRC, you cannot inject `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` into your controllers since they are providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `$stateProvider` or `$urlRouterProvider` ([providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)) in a controller because those [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) are just made for configuration injection. It can be uses in any `angular.module('myApp').config()` you want but you can't user providers in a controller. In controllers you could only inject `$state` ([modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), services, factories, e.g.):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $state) {}
```

This little [code snippet shows you how to create a Service, a Factory and a Provider](https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232).

Comment: So how could i use my multi-step form with ui-router without putting the config in app.js?

Comment: @VincentDucroquet what exactly is your problem? Your router configuration should be fine in `app.config()`.

Comment: On a another page, when I have the .config in my app.js, I have an error :
str.replace is not a function
    at replaceAll (toolbar.js?v=636305309810171550&l=fr&u=636306206076525625:5)

Comment: When I comment the .config part, i don't have the error anymore

Comment: And it says me "form" is already defined. It put a breakpoint juste before the $stateProvider, It passes twice in the $stateprovider, i really don't know why

Comment: @VincentDucroquet could you create a new question for your problem please and provide all the stuff to reproduce your problem? I think this question: "StateProvider somewhere else than app.js in AngularJS" is solved. Please link the new question here and I will help you. Please dont forget to mark the right answer.

Comment: @VincentDucroquet please create your new question and link it. I will help ya m8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026319/state-x-is-already-defined-angularjs-ui-router